# How to identify the type of Sandbox in Apex?

Tags: apex, sandbox

I need to check the type of Sandbox to verify whether it is one of the following

- Partial Copy Sandbox
- Full Sandbox
- Developer Sandbox

The Organization object helps in identifying if its a sandbox as follows:

`[SELECT Id, isSandbox FROM Organization LIMIT 1].isSandbox`

But, how to check the **Type of Sandbox**?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I don't think there's a straightforward solution.

As you've said, we have the [Organization](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api.meta/api/sforce_api_objects_organization.htm) SObject which we can query to find certain environment information, such as:

```
SELECT Id, InstanceName, IsSandbox, Name, OrganizationType FROM Organization
```

This will tell us if we're on a sandbox environment, but it won't tell us which of sandbox it is.

The best solution I can offer is to include sandbox type in the sandbox type when creating them.

So if you have the following environments:

- Prod: *CompanyName*
- Sandbox: *CompanyName*.UAT
- Sandbox: *CompanyName*.QA
- Sandbox: *CompanyName*.DEV
- Sandbox: *CompanyName*.DEVPRO

You will be able to query **Organization.Name** to find the current environment type.

It's pretty messy and requires the use of a naming convention in order to work, but I think it's the easiest way for now. Probably worth a post on the Ideas site, as it would be a pretty useful feature.

Comment: Since there is no way to determine, this is closest solution for the question. Idea here: https://success.salesforce.com/ideaView?id=0873000000083sJAAQ

Comment: Tried it in 2023 and this is not the right answer. Doesn't work. The organization name is always the one in prod.

Answer (score 1):

Depending on the name of your Sandbox, you could retrieve this information from the base URL.

Something like:

```
String baseURL = URL.getSalesforceBaseUrl().getHost();
String testPrefix = '--test';

Boolean isTestSandbox = baseURL.containsIgnoreCase(testPrefix);

System.debug('Value of baseURL: ' + baseURL);
System.debug('Value of isTestSandbox: ' + isTestSandbox);
```

Debug results:

`[4]|DEBUG|Value of baseURL: companyname--test.csXX.my.salesforce.com
 [5]|DEBUG|Value of isTestSandbox: true`

Answer (score 1):

here is a way to identify sandbox type in Apex...

```
Integer storageLimit = OrgLimits.getMap().get('DataStorageMB').getLimit();
String sandboxType;
switch on storageLimit{
    when 5 {
        sandboxType = 'Developer Edition';
    }
    when 200 {
        sandboxType = 'Developer';
    }
    when 1024 {
        sandboxType = 'Developer Pro';
    }
    when 5120 {
        sandboxType = 'Partial Copy';
    }
    when else {
        sandboxType = 'Full Copy';
    }
}
System.debug(sandboxType);
```

Answer (score 0):

I have a use case where I want to create sample test data with a SandboxPostCopy class. It runs into this problem how do I know if it's a dev with no data or a partial or full with data.

I thought of the solution if you query for Account data, the probably most used object in the system, and if records are returned then you know it's a full or partial and if there are no records then it's a dev.

Answer (score -3):

As we all know sandbox username looks like "behera@mycompany.com.dev "

dev- is the sandbox name, How can we get it this dynamically ?

Use below code :-

```
if(UserInfo.getUserName().substringAfterLast('.com')!= null)
                    contact.Email = contactInfo.Email+'.'+UserInfo.getUserName().substringAfterLast('.');
                else
                    contact.Email = contactInfo.Email;
}

UserInfo.getUserName().substringAfterLast('.') - will give you sandbox name.
```

UserInfo.getUserName().substringAfterLast('.com') will tell you whether anything is there after " .com ". if not there that means we are in production otherwise in sandbox. 
We can also used same method to identify type of org like prod or non prod. There is another approach for this.

Organization org = [select id,IsSandbox from Organization];
org.IsSandbox = true if it a sandbox. It willwork classs of higher version.

Feel free to suggest more.

Comment: if its a sandbox, how to check the type of sandbox?

Comment: This solution may not work if users change their username.

Comment: This doesn't answer the question, it only shows the name of the sandbox, not the type. Also only works if the current user's username ends in `.com`.