# how to find the environment type of salesforce sandbox

Tags: soql, sandbox, environment

I wanna know the type of environment my salesforce org uses.
I ran the following query:

```
SELECT Id, InstanceName, IsSandbox, Name, OrganizationType FROM Organization
```

It says the organization type is 'Enterprise Edition' but I want to know whether this sandbox is a 'developer sandbox' or 'developer pro' sandbox.

I have no information on how and when this sandbox was created and also 'Organization.Name' does not work for the query.

I have already gone through this [https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/110760/how-to-identify-the-type-of-sandbox-in-apex](http://link)

but since I dont have any information on how the sandbox was created, I think I am not able to query Organization.Name in my query.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to identify the type of Sandbox in Apex?](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/110760/how-to-identify-the-type-of-sandbox-in-apex)

Comment: @TusharSharma I already have checked the post mentioned in the link, that's why I have put a comment that "I have no information on how and when this sandbox was created and also 'Organization.Name' does not work for the query.".

Comment: Then you should mention this question in your post as reference otherwise this question will be closed shortly.

Comment: @TusharSharma: thanks for the comment. I have mentioned the same in my question.

Answer (score 1):

I think the easiest way might be go to Setup>Monitor>System Overview and see that amount of Data Storage available as that is different for each type of sandbox.

See the image - this is a bit of a simplistic way of doing it but it will allow you to recognise the sandbox type. So as I have 200mb of storage this is a Developer Sandbox.

[image: System overview shot]

Comment: Just trying to find how to retrieve this using SOQL for the Org's details.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think there's a straightforward way to obtain it with SOQL, in the sandbox itself. You could do a Tooling API callout to the production org and query the [SandboxInfo](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_tooling.meta/api_tooling/tooling_api_objects_sandboxinfo.htm) table. It's not great because you'd need credentials for the production org (consider using "named credentials"?)

In the sandbox itself, again with a Tooling API callout you can get the [limits](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_rest.meta/api_rest/dome_limits.htm), including storage usage & max available space. Combine it with info from https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=limits_sandbox.htm&type=0 and you're getting somewhere...